# Multiprocessing runs at 100% forever

Tags: python, multiprocessing, networkx

Can someone please explain why:

```
import networkx as nx
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def work(item):
    pths = []
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, item, endNode,cutoff=maxLen-1):
        path.insert(0,startNode)
        pths.append(path)
    return pths

def init_worker(Gr, st,ed, cl):
    global G, startNode, endNode, maxLen

    print "process initializing", mp.current_process()
    G, startNode, endNode, maxLen = Gr, st, ed, cl
    G.remove_node(startNode)

def multi_core(graph, sourceChem, sinkChem, maxLen, minLen):
    paths = []
    startNeighbours = graph[sourceChem].keys()
    p = mp.Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(graph,sourceChem, sinkChem, 9))
    paths = p.map(work, startNeighbours, chunksize=(len(startNeighbours)/mp.cpu_count()))
    for i in paths:
        if len(i) != 0:
            for j in i:
                paths.append(j)        
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return paths

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print multi_core(nx.read_graphml("RESTKegg.graphml"), 'C00025', 'C00029', 4, 2)
```

Runs forever at 100% core usage across all cores? I've used code similar to this but with out a `return` in multi_core, is that what is causing the problem?

**Edit:** Running:

```
graph = nx.read_graphml("minimal.graphml")
startNeighbours = graph['C00030'].keys()
init_worker(graph, 'C00030', 'C00072', 4)
for i in startNeighbours:
    work(i)
```

As an unthreaded version returns fine.

**Update:** I built a test bed to remove the code from the rest of the program and it appears that the code works outside the program fine, and that it appears to be having problems with my Kivy front-end.

Comment: Which return statement?

Comment: Sorry, the one in `multi_core`.

Comment: Have you tried running the worker without multiprocessing? Does it return fine?

Comment: Yeah no problems without multiple processors.

Comment: can you post the content of a very minimal RESTKegg.graphml or link to an equivalent?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxtgl690g55ucf6/RESTKegg.graphml

Comment: That's non-minimal, but it's the exact one I'm using, I'll make a minimal one now. Edit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3ubkwk0mwt3esw/Ascorbate%3BAscorbic%20acid%3BL-Ascorbate%3BL-Ascorbic%20acid%3BVitamin%20CReduced%20acceptor%3BAH2%3BHydrogen-donor%3BDonor.graphml

Comment: Open up your RESTKegg.graphml and ctrl-F C00025 please, is is there?

Comment: Yes sorry. Long story and my bad. The file is fine.

Comment: That code snippet appears fine outside the main program, but when run in conjunction with the Kivy GUI code it causes the long runs.